# Fake proof, and a claim!

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series, fake-proofs

It is well-known that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$$ diverges, because $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n\neq0$
But look at this as a fake proof.  Someone claimed that he can show $$s=-1+1-1+1-1+1+\cdots \sim \log 2$$
 I Know that  is $\color{red} {\bf \text{fake}}$, but I am looking for the idea behind his claim.

I tried to $s=1,s=-1 ,s=\frac12$ but I can't find some more idea.
Again I say, I know that is $\color{red} {\bf \text{fake}}$. but may be an fantastic  idea behind his claim.

for example my trial was like below 
$$s=(-1+1)+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+...=0\\$$simplify the parentheses
$$s=-1+(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+...=-1\\$$ rearrange and simplify parentheses
or pick up one $+1$ and simplify parentheses $$s=+1+(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+...=1$$ or 
$$s=(-1+1)+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+...=\\-1-\underbrace{(-1+1)-(-1+1)-(-1+1)...}_{-s}\\\to \\s=-1+s \\s=\frac12$$ Now :is there any idea to show $s\to $ any other number ?
 for example can you show $s\to \frac{3}{$}$ ?

I think It is necessary to see some $\color{red} {\bf \text{fake}}$ proof like this , because some student or others may ask about them .

Thanks for any hint in advance.

Comment: In what sense are you summing this?

Comment: You could use the idea of the proof of the Riemann Rearrangement Theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt :Students sometimes ask like this , and do like what i did above . I hate fake proof(s) but ,I must know them ,see them and sense a mistake behind them to show the wrong way .

Comment: Are you asking what is wrong with the "fake proof?"

Comment: @SahibaArora : No , I know whats wrong here ,,,but I want to see how many wrong answer may be exist , or what are the Ideas behind the fake proofs like that .

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. Sorry. You are stating someone has claimed an (unstated here) fake proof, and you want us to find the fake proof?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:I mean for example  $s \to \frac13$ ? or show $s \to \frac{3}{7}$ ! or finally $$s \to \log 2$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is all fake because you are manipulating a divergent series as if it were convergent. If we are allowed this, we can show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ is equal to any real number.

Indeed, suppose $a$ is a real number. Then
$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n &= -1 + 1 -1+1-1+1-+\cdots \\
&= (-1+1)+(-1+1)+\cdots \\
&= 0 \\
&= 0a \\
&= ((-1+1)+(-1+1)+\cdots)a \\
&= ((1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots)a \\
&=(1+((-1+1)+(-1+1)+\cdots))a \\
&=(1+0)a \\
&=a \\
\end{align*} $$

Comment: :thanks a ton. It was clear and very simple idea.

Comment: It follows that the identity map from the real numbers to itself is a constant and therefore continuous thank you!

Comment: @yanko It also proves that $\mathbb{R}=\{0\}$ is a finite set. haha

Comment: @Khosrotash if this is the answer you were searching for then, when you can, accept it, please ;-)

Comment: @trying :If I see the mistakes in wrong solution , I can describe "Whats wrong here"  better ,isn't it?

Comment: @trying xD Be patient, he probably has to wait a bit longer before he **can** accept anything.

Comment: @John Griffin then it also proves that the identity map from a finite set to itself is continuous wow!

Comment: You go from$$-1+1-1+1+\dots$$to$$(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\dots$$to$$0+0+\dots=0$$this conveys the message the negative terms "weigh" as much as the positive terms.  Under most regularizations of divergent series, you will find that not all terms weight the same.  For example, in the Cesàro summation, the first terms have more weight because more partial sums will contain them.  Likewise for Abel summations.  To put the gist of it there, for the Abel summation, the $n$th parenthesis behaves like $(-1+1)\sim_0-x^{2n-1}+x^{2n}$. This is not equal to zero, and this small error "adds up" to give $-1/2$

Comment: Why are you criticizing another's answers to a post you also answered, @SimplyBeautifulArt?  That's a bit petty, no?

Comment: @amWhy Criticizing? I merely thought it informative to add such comments. Many people do not consider the order of a series to matter much, and when dealing with the evaluation of a divergent series, I really do think it helps conceptually to add "weight" based on where a particular terms exists in the series. I never said there was anything wrong with this (as far as answering goes) $\ddot\smile$ it certainly answers the question nicely IMO.

Comment: Well, weight, as far as Abel sums go.  Not so much for some of the other regularizations.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  weight?  or wait? :-)

Comment: @amWhy weight, usually measured in kg unless you happen to be American.

Answer (score 11):

In general, there is no way to relate a divergent series to just *any value* you want.  Rather, you need to *define* what a divergent series is.

For a convergent infinite series, we generally agree that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\equiv\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$$

This has two effects: it defines what an infinite series is, and it does so **uniquely**.  That is, from here, you can go on to prove various mathematical properties of our infinite series.

Interestingly though, if this series does not converge absolutely, there exists a rearrangement $b_n$ such that $b_n$ goes through all the natural $k\in[1,\infty)$, though not in order, and

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\ne\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N a_{b_n}$$

This is known as the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem), which helps me stress the point that

**you need to define what your gibberish means!**

Or else you'll expect something to work, but it doesn't.

> To emphasize, if I haven't done so enough already, just because you moved some terms around does **not** mean you have the original series.  In order to move terms around rigorously, you should, for a convergent series, check if your rearrangements are doable within the partial sums!  If you can't fit such rearrangements in the partial sums, your rearrangement is likely **invalid**.

In the same manner, the various definitions of what a divergent series means only assign **one value** to each series.  For example, we could use the [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) to define

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\equiv\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^ka_n$$

Or we could use the stronger [Abel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation) to define

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\equiv\lim_{x\to1^-}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_nx^n$$

Or we could use a Ramanujan summation or a Borel summation or what have you, but each of these definitions only gives one value per divergent series!

That said, what does a divergent sum mean to you?  If it is any of the above, you will find that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n=-\frac12$$

Comment: Jeez, why are people upvoting me in less than 25 seconds of me posting this?  Please take the time to read first!

Comment: @Bungo Perhaps you should read the entire post first?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I skimmed right past that!

Comment: Jeez you youngsters, making statements and upvoting me before you read my full post...

Comment: Ugh, and there comes the anonymous downvotes that don't care to explain themselves.

Comment: GH Hardy's book "Divergent Series" explores some of this material

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  You're loving it.  Don't pretend protest. You've posted links to your answer in chats, which are not really about protesting folks upvotes of your answer, but rather drawing attention to it.  I notice your comment too, about downvotes.  Maybe they came from users who did read your post?

Comment: @amWhy :-) I just found it startling that I would receive *multiple upvotes* in well under a minutes.  Such an event is quite irregular.

Comment: Well, as you seem to acknowledge, @SimplyBeautifulArt, that says nothing of the quality of an answer, but more, perhaps. due to the number of friends one has. And if  that's the case, the upvotes mean little.

Comment: @amWhy Probably. But if that's the case, my friends are certainly stalking me around >.>

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  lol!

Answer (score 5):

I gather that you're asking if it's possible, for any $x\in\mathbb R$, to construct an incorrect proof that the series has value $x$. The trivial answer is yes: Incorrect proofs can prove anything! But here's a more concrete idea...

First of all, the following is a true theorem:

- For any $x\in\mathbb R$, there is a series of $\pm 1$ terms whose Cesaro sum is $x$.

Now, the Cesaro sum of the original series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ is $-\frac12$. That much is unambiguous. But if you tacitly imply the following two falsehoods to someone:

- Rearranging a Cesaro summable series does not change the Cesaro sum. (Wrong: It often does.)
- The Cesaro sum of a series is the same as the ordinary sum. (Wrong: It's different.)

Then you can convince them that the sum is $x$.

Comment: (Note: Not limited to *just* Cesàro sums)

Comment: @amWhy x.x I never said it was wrong, I merely implied that this answer extends to pretty much every rigorous interpretation of a divergent series.  What is wrong with that? Surely that only makes this a better answer?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  You're right; I'll delete my comment above.